# Turn php object in to date format

Tags: php, mysql, string, date, object

I'm getting the birth date from my users from a form with a select dropdown for month, day and year. The plugin I'm using for this (Pie Register) stores this value as an object (I guess) in my database, which looks something like this:

a:1:{s:4:"date";a:3:{s:2:"mm";s:2:"**01**";s:2:"dd";s:2:"**23**";s:2:"yy";s:4:"**1965**";}}

I tried the following:

```
<?php
    $mydata = serialize(get_user_meta($uid, 'pie_date_4', true));
        echo    $mydata[53], $mydata[54],"/",
                $mydata[35], $mydata[36],"/",
                $mydata[71], $mydata[72], $mydata[73], $mydata[74];
?>
```

This gives me the date as I want it: **23/01/1965**

This is obviously not the right way to do it... As I can't really fix the storing proces from the select field to the database my question is: **How can I get the date by calling just the strings I need?**

Comment: That data looks to be serialized already, so you would want to call `unserialize` and then reference the array values appropriately afterwards... `$array['date']['mm']` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the wrong way, your data is already serialized, you need to use :

```
$value = get_user_meta($uid, 'pie_date_4', true);

// unserialize value, and get array from date index
$unserialize = unserialize($value);
$unserialize = $unserialize['date'];

// create date object
$date = new DateTime($unserialize['yy'] .'-'. $unserialize['mm'] .'-'. $unserialize['dd']);

// format date
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```